# Push Opens in parse-dashboard is always N/A

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, parse-server, parse-dashboard

I build a Parse server to send notifications to ios android android app.
So I use React Native to build app receiving these  notifications on IOS and Android. Sending notification to devices succeeds. I can open notification and it leads to my app. 
But in dash-board of parse-server, at Past Push, the number of Push Opens is always N/A. 
[image]

Is there any way for my react native app to send back to Parse server when I open these notifications?
Thanks in advances.

Comment: did you find its answer?

Comment: I have not found its answer. So I am using Onesignal instead of parse server

Comment: Do you maintain separate user database for onesignal?

Comment: User database is stored by onesignal server. If you want to get database, you can call API to Onesignal, and it returns csv file. You can read document API Onesignal.